# How can I access the Tabbed Properties View in Eclipse programatically?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'd like to get access to the Tabbed Properties View in order to change the displayed tab programatically. When the selection is changed, the default behaviour is to show the same tab for the new selection (if they share a tab descriptor) or else to show the last known tab for that selection. I need to be able to set the tab based on program conditions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ask for IPropertySheetPage.class adapter from Properties View workbench part, then cast it to org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed.TabbedPropertySheetPage in order to call setSelectedTab() on it.

Cheers,
Max

Comment: Many thanks, @Max. That's just the ticket.

Edit: It seems I can't upvote your answer due to a lack of reputation.

Comment: steve_c, I guess you should be able to accept the answer as an author